# ORA-00600 , Arguments: [KGL-heap-size-exceeded]

Tags: oracle, sqlexception, ora-00600

My oracle 12c (12.1.0.1) database stop working last night (actually It worked but very very slow) , and started throwing the following exception:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments::
>   [KGL-heap-size-exceeded], [0x07B292C58], [0], [524314616], [], [], [],
>   [], [], [], [], []

Have not idea what is causing this problem, and I can't find any useful information. Does anyone knows about this "KGL heap size exceeded"? Thanks

Comment: ORA-600 usually means you have to raise a ticket at Oracle support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ORA-00600 errors are bugs in Oracle's software and should first be investigated on [support.oracle.com](http://support.oracle.com).  Many of the support documents are not public and cannot be found on any other search engine.

When you get to that site, search for "ora-600 tool", which will bring you to a special page.  That page will ask you for the first argument.  Enter `KGL-heap-size-exceeded`, hit "Look-up Error", and it will show a single document with more information - "ORA-600 [KGL-heap-size-exceeded] (Doc ID 1662971.1)".

That document includes links to 5 different bugs.  I'm not sure which is the relevant bug, it depends on your version and exactly how the bug happens.  And there are many bugs that aren't even published on My Oracle Support.

After you've looked on the website, and tried either solving or avoiding the problem, *then* you might want to create a ticket.  But do not immediately create a ticket for every ORA-00600 error or you will waste a tremendous amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

There is usually a trace file associated with this error which gives a details of the error. in order to resolve you need to set this parameter 
alter system set "_kgl_large_heap_warning_threshold"=88608 scope=spfile sid='*';
In the example above I set the value to 8MB.